# Close modal as soon as another one is pressed

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, jsx

I want a modal to close once a different modal is pressed, but I'm not sure on how to do  it.
Essentially, if modal1 is pressed, it should show the contents of modal1, but as soon as modal2 is pressed,modal1 should disappear and only modal2 should show it's contents. How do I go about this?
I've tried to set it up with an open and close in the onclick but only had problems.
This is how I've got my code currently set up:

```
 const [openQueueList, setOpenQueueList] = useState(false);
  const handleOpenQueue = () => {
    setOpenQueueList(true);
  };
  const [openRoomlist, setOpenRoomlist] = useState(false);
  const handleOpenRoom = () => {
    setOpenRoomlist(true);
  };
  const [openRoomQueueList, setOpenRoomQueueList] = useState(false);
  const handleOpenRoomQueue = () => {
    setOpenRoomQueueList(true);
  };
```

in the return

```
<div class="modal"> 
            <div >
              {openQueueList ? 
                <TrackTable></TrackTable>
               : null}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal"> 
            <div >
              {openRoomlist ? 
               <LobbyUsers> </LobbyUsers>
               : null}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal"> 
            <div >
              {openRoomQueueList ? 
                <QueueSection></QueueSection>
               : null}
            </div>
```

Triggering the buttons

```
           <button onClick={handleOpenRoomQueue}>
              <QueueMusicIcon></QueueMusicIcon>
            </button>
            <button onClick={handleOpenRoom}>
              <GroupIcon ></GroupIcon>
            </button>
            <button onClick={handleOpenQueue}>
              <AudiotrackIcon></AudiotrackIcon>
            </button>
```

Comment: can you please add some code i.e the code where you are triggering the open modal event

Comment: I knew  I forgot something, added it in now, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a state for each modal you could give each a key.

State would look like this

```
const [currentModal, openModal] = useState(null);
```

Then to open

```
<button onClick={() => openModal('queueList')}>Queue List</button>
<button onClick={() => openModal('roomList')}>Room List</button>
<button onClick={() => openModal('roomQueueList')}>Room Queue List</button>
```

Then your modals would look something like:

```
<div className="modal">

  {currentModal === 'queueList' ? 
    <TrackTable></TrackTable>
  : null}

  {currentModal === 'roomList' ?
    <LobbyUsers> </LobbyUsers>
  : null}

  {currentModal === 'roomQueueList' ?
    <QueueSection></QueueSection>
  : null}

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, yvw!